# Docker Compose with awslogs driver: How to get better stream names?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using the [awslogs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/#awslogs-stream) driver in docker compose and wondering if there is a better way to control the cloudwatch log stream naming.

Specifying `awslogs-stream` as shown below doesn't work well if your service runs on multiple containers/nodes due to performance issues. If you don't specify it, you just end up with the random container ID which also isn't great and will get ugly over time.

It looks like [ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html) (which I'm not using) supports `awslogs-stream-prefix` but that is not shown as an option for docker compose or the awslogs driver.

Am I missing some other option to get more meaningful yet unique stream names?

```
    logging:
      driver: awslogs      
      options:
        mode: non-blocking
        awslogs-region: us-east-1
        awslogs-group: mygroup
        awslogs-stream: mystream  # Can't do this with multiple containers
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tag** option specifies how to format a tag that identifies the container’s log messages. By default, the system uses the container ID for the log stream name if you don't specify it. To override this behavior, specify a tag option. It's a golang template.

```
logging:
   driver: "awslogs"
   options:
      awslogs-region: "us-east-1"
      awslogs-group: "mygroup"
      tag: "{{.ImageName}}/{{.Name}}/{{.ID}}"
```

so, your log stream name would be in this manner (*imagename/containerName/containerID*)

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer since it looks like a reasonable approach if it works, though I have moved on from this problem and won't be able to test it right away. I ended up just ignoring the issue and using the [awslogs](https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs) command line tool, which allows analyzing logs at the group level so I'm never looking at the ugly container-specific stream names.

Comment: This won't work if your ImageName has ":" in it because of limitations with AWS CloudWatch API.  You'll need to either remove it or do something like this from the docker-compose docs:

`tag='{{ with split .ImageName ":" }}{{join . "_"}}{{end}}-{{.ID}}'`

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/#tag